# how to set the border color in pdf using itextsharp

Tags: itext

I want to change the border bottom color for the tr tag in html table, which convert the pdf using Itextsharp. it is not working properly. By default black color is coming up as a result. Can any one suggest me how to achieve this uanig Itextsharp.

Thanks in Advance.
Kalai.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
StyleSheet style = new StyleSheet();
style.LoadTagStyle("tr", "border-bottom-color", "Yellow");
objects = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader("YOUR HTML"), style);
for (int k = 0; k < objects.Count; ++k)
{
    document.AddElement((IElement)objects[k]);
}
```